Prisma ORM issue while building project on VPS hosting or Vercel hosting


I have an issue with prisma ORM when I'm trying to deploy (build) project, the DB doesn't work on Vercel or doesn't build on VPS hosting, but it builds and wroks well localy
package.json:
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev", 
    "build": "prisma generate && next build", - this is what prisma documentation suggests 
    "analyze": "ANALYZE=true next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "typecheck": "tsc --noEmit",
    "lint": "next lint && npm run lint:stylelint",
    "lint:stylelint": "stylelint '**/*.css' --cache",
    "jest": "jest",
    "jest:watch": "jest --watch",
    "prettier:check": "prettier --check \"**/*.{ts,tsx}\"",
    "prettier:write": "prettier --write \"**/*.{ts,tsx}\"",
    "test": "npm run prettier:check && npm run lint && npm run typecheck && npm run jest",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "storybook:build": "storybook build",
    "prisma-seed": "tsx prisma/seed.ts",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate" - this is another script what prisma documentation suggests 
    },

I tried two different scripts one by one:

"build": "prisma generate && next build"
"postinstall": "prisma generate"

The second one works when I build project localy, and Vercel builds it well but it dosen't  work. VPS hosting dosent work, dosen't build it at all.
My .env file is correct and on Vercel it was added as a variable. Either I added it into my VPS hosting.
